# A method I cannot find in Python official documentation

Tags: python

I was reading python cookbook and came upon this recipe:

If you have a slice instance `s`, you can get more information about it by looking at its
`s.start`, `s.stop`, and `s.step` attributes, respectively. For example:

```sh
>>> a = slice(5, 50, 2)
>>> a.start
5
>>> a.stop
50
>>> a.step
2
>>>
```

In addition, you can map a slice onto a sequence of a specific size by using its indi
ces(size) method. This returns a tuple (start, stop, step) where all values have
been suitably limited to fit within bounds (as to avoid IndexError exceptions when
indexing). For example:

```sh
>>> s = 'HelloWorld'
>>> a.indices(len(s))
(5, 10, 2)
>>> for i in range(*a.indices(len(s))):
... print(s[i])
...
W
r
d
```

I looked up `indices()` method in Python official documentation but couldn't find it. Is the book making a mistake here? If not, what does this method do?

Comment: [Here's the documentation you didn't find.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slice.indices)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `help(a)` on your initialized slice object, I found the following -

```
 |  indices(...)
 |      S.indices(len) -> (start, stop, stride)
 |
 |      Assuming a sequence of length len, calculate the start and stop
 |      indices, and the stride length of the extended slice described by
 |      S. Out of bounds indices are clipped in a manner consistent with the
 |      handling of normal slices.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find it if you go to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) and search for `slice.indices` in the top-right search box. First result is [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=slice%20indices#slice.indices):

> `slice.indices(self, length)`
> This method takes a single integer argument length and computes information about the slice that the slice object would describe if applied to a sequence of length items. It returns a tuple of three integers; respectively these are the start and stop indices and the step or stride length of the slice. Missing or out-of-bounds indices are handled in a manner consistent with regular slices.

Answer (score 2):

I found the documentation not quite clear, so after understanding what it actually does, I decided to share the explanation in my words:

A *Slice* object defines `start:stop:step` values, and is a way to effectively pack those 3 values into a single object (variable):

```py
>>> s = Slice(1, 2)
>>> text[1:2] == text[s]
True
```

As you can see above, a slice is automatically unpacked, using colon `:` separators. You can't unpack it using comma `,` separators and need to do it manually like so:

```py
>>> s.start, s.stop, s.step
(1, 2, None)
```

Perhaps default values being `None` is something that should be fixed (default start should be `0`, default step should be `1`, and you must precise the stop), but it works when slicing, also with literals:

```py
>>> slice(1)
slice(None, 1, None)
>>> "Hello World"[slice(1)]
'H'
>>> "Hello World"[None:1:None]
'H'
```

However, not only you can't unpack a slice using an asterisk, but also `range` will not work with `None`:

```py
>>> s = slice(10, 20)
>>> range(*s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: range() argument after * must be an iterable, not slice

>>> range(s.start, s.stop, s.step)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

You need to replace `None` with default values:

```py
>>> s = slice(13)
>>> args = (s.start or 0, s.stop, 1 if s.step is None else s.step)
>>> args
(0, 13, 1)

>>> args = (s.start or 0, s.stop, s.step or 1)  # step == 0 is invalid anyway
>>> args
(0, 13, 1)

>>> range(*args)
range(0, 13)
```

However, while slicing will automatically clamp values to a valid range, using `range` object and accessing an element using a single integer index, rather than a slice, can cause an *IndexError*:

```py
>>> text = "Hello World"
>>> s = slice(7, 20)
>>> text[s]
'orld'
>>> for i in range(s.start, s.stop):
...     print(i)
...     print(text[i])
...     
7
o
8
r
9
l
10
d
11

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 3, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

So using `slice` together with `range()` require both manual unpacking and clamping to values in bounds. Both problems are solved with `slice.indices()`:

```py
>>> text = "Hello World"
>>> s = slice(7, 20)
>>> [text[i] for i in range(*s.indices(len(text)))]
['o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

`slice.indices()` expects an argument and doesn't accept `float("inf")`, so if for some reason you want to resign from clamping, you need to fall back to a previous method or use `s.indices(s.stop)` if `stop` is positive (not clamping with negative `stop` doesn't make sense anyway).